# How to check the existance of a stored procedure before creating one

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I know that there are a lot of questions asking this but I don't see why this code is failing but the 'BEGIN' starting the Stored Procedure says it's expecting "EXTERNAL" which doesn't make sense.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Insert_ToTable'))
BEGIN
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Insert_ToTable]
    AS
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
        BEGIN TRY

            //Stored Procedure Code
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

            DECLARE @ErrMsg nvarchar(4000), @ErrSeverity int

            SELECT @ErrMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
                   @ErrSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY()

            RAISERROR(@ErrMsg, @ErrSeverity, 1)
        END CATCH   

        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    END
END
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `CREATE PROCEDURE` must be the only statement in a batch.  You cannot conditionally create it if it doesn't exist because the `CREATE PROCEDURE` is preceded by the `if` statement.  You can however, conditionally drop and then always create it.

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Insert_ToTable]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
  drop procedure [dbo].[Insert_ToTable]
go

create procedure [dbo].[Insert_ToTable]
as
  -- code
go

grant execute on [dbo].[Insert_ToTable] to whomever
go
```

### Edit #1

Since you are using an external tool, you could run the following statement to test to see if the procedure exists:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Insert_ToTable]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
  select 'exists' as [status]
else
  select 'missing' as [status]
```

Then you could easily test the `[status]` field and only run the `create procedure` statement from the external tool if the status is *missing*.

Comment: I don't want to drop/create the stored procedure because it's not performant.  It's running in an external tool in the database so I need a deterministic output without SQL errors being thrown that the procedure doesn't exist.

Comment: Since you are using an external tool, why can't you test to see if the proc exists first and only run the `create procedure` statement if it doesn't exists (as a separate statement)?  See *Edit #1* above.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up doing.  I was just hoping for a cleaner way.  Thanks for all of the answers!

Answer (score 1):

Another really, I mean REALLY ugly way is creating stored procedure using EXEC.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (...)
BEGIN
    EXEC('CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Insert_ToTable] ...')
END
```

Don't use it if you don't have to.